# Why is json data empty when using stringify when sending data using ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, stringify

When I use JSON.stringify, the data that is in it can't be send for some reason. But when I remove JSON.stringify, it does send and I would like to know why? Is there a way to controll the json data in PHP file without using stringify? Any help is much appreciated!

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: "***/server/jsonp/data",
        callback:"test",
        success: jsonSuccess
    });


    function jsonSuccess( data ){


        for( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ){

            if ( i == 0 ) {

                var formData = {name:"tolga",age:"25"}; // test object 

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "wp-content/themes/flex/saveJsonInfo.php",
                    data: { info: JSON.stringify(data[i]) }
                }).done(function(data2) {

                    console.log(data2);

                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The json data that I receive is something like this:

```
test([{"EniNumber":"22325326","Name":"Test Fi","StartDate":"\/Date(1381788000000)\/","Rows":[{"T":42878,"Y":51.880965,"X":4.395925,"D":14.56},{"T":42879,"Y":51.880967,"X":4.395925,"D":14.56},{"T":42880,"Y":51.880967,"X":4.395925,"D":14.59}]}, {"EniNumber":"12312312","Name":"Test Fi 2","StartDate":"\/Date(13817880021300)\/","Rows":[{"T":42878,"Y":51.880965,"X":4.395925,"D":14.56},{"T":42879,"Y":51.880967,"X":4.395925,"D":14.56},{"T":42880,"Y":51.880967,"X":4.395925,"D":14.59}]}])
```

This is how my PHP example file looks:

```
$json_data = $_POST['info'];

if( isset($json_data) ){
    echo json_encode( $json_data );
} else {
    echo json_encode( "What happened?" );
}
```

Comment: what does data[i] contain?

Comment: see test([{"EniNumber..."}])